# Plotting solution 2nd ODE using Euler

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ode, eulers-number

I have used the Equation of Motion (Newtons Law) for a simple spring and mass scenario incorporating it into the given 2nd ODE equation y" + (k/m)x = 0; y(0) = 3; y'(0) = 0.

Using the Euler method and the exact solution to solve the problem, I have been able to run and receive some ok results. However, when I execute a plot of the results I get this diagonal line across the oscillating results that I am after.

[Current plot output with diagonal line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVDGn.png)

Can anyone help point out what is causing this issue, and how I can fix it please?

MY CODE:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy import Function, dsolve, Eq, Derivative, sin, cos, symbols
from sympy.abc import x, i
import math


# Given is y" + (k/m)x = 0; y(0) = 3; y'(0) = 0

# Parameters
h = 0.01;  #Step Size
t = 50.0;  #Time(sec)
k = 1;     #Spring Stiffness
m = 1;     #Mass
x0 = 3;
v0 = 0;

# Exact Analytical Solution
x_exact = x0*cos(math.sqrt(k/m)*t);
v_exact = -x0*math.sqrt(k/m)*sin(math.sqrt(k/m)*t);

# Eulers Method
x = np.zeros( int( t/h ) );
v = np.zeros( int( t/h ) );
x[1] = x0;
v[1] = v0;
x_exact = np.zeros( int( t/h ) );
v_exact = np.zeros( int( t/h ) );
te      = np.zeros( int( t/h ) );
x_exact[1] = x0;
v_exact[1] = v0;


#print(len(x));

for i in range(1, int(t/h) - 1):    #MAIN LOOP
    x[i+1] = x[i] + h*v[i];
    v[i+1] = v[i] - h*k/m*x[i];
    te[i]  = i * h
    x_exact[i] = x0*cos(math.sqrt(k/m)* te[i]);
    v_exact[i] = -x0*math.sqrt(k/m)*sin(math.sqrt(k/m)* te[i]);
#    print(x_exact[i], '\t'*2, x[i]);

#plot
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'svg'
plt.plot(te, x_exact, te ,v_exact)
plt.title("DISPLACEMENT")
plt.xlabel("Time (s)")
plt.ylabel("Displacement (m)")
plt.grid(linewidth=0.3)
```

Comment: You did not fill the allocated array to the end, so that you have trailing zeros that connect the end of the graph back to the origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An in some details more direct computation is

```py
te = np.arange(0,t,h)
N = len(te)

w = (k/m)**0.5
x_exact = x0*np.cos(w*te);
v_exact = -x0*w*np.sin(w*te);

plt.plot(te, x_exact, te ,v_exact)
```

resulting in

[image: plot of exact solution]

Note that arrays in python start at the index zero,

```py
x = np.empty(N)
v = np.empty(N)
x[0] = x0;
v[0] = v0;

for i in range(N - 1):    #MAIN LOOP
    x[i+1] = x[i] + h*v[i];
    v[i+1] = v[i] - h*k/m*x[i];

plt.plot(te, x, te ,v)
```

then gives the plot

[image]

with the expected increasing amplitude.

Comment: Thank you for your enlightening description. I'm still getting the hang of utilizing python. You have helped me for sure!